# Is it possible to change the text in a StringGrid cell immediately after adding a new row or column in Lazarus/Delphi?

Tags: delphi, text, lazarus, caption, stringgrid

I am trying to perform:

```
Form3.StringGrid1.Cells[0,Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount] := 'Hoofdstad';
```

*after* performing:

```
Onderdelen := Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount;
Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount := Onderdelen + 1;
```

It gives an error every time, it will say that I am trying to change the text of a cell that doesnt exist (yet).
I am still very new to this language, I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: The last row index is `Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount - 1`.

Comment: What do you mean? Im trying to add a row

Comment: When you add a row, the last valid index is still `RowCount - 1`. Adding a row doesn't change the fact that it's zero-based, so the last cell index (the new last row) is `RowCount - 1` - it doesn't change.

Comment: Gotcha, stupid mistake of me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cells` property uses 0-based indexing.  The index of the first row is 0 and the index of the last row is `RowCount-1`.  When you add a new row, the `RowCount` increases, but the index of the last row is still `RowCount-1`.

So, when you are trying to use this:

`Form3.StringGrid1.Cells[0,Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount] := 'Hoofdstad';`

You are going out of bounds, because `Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount` is 1 too high.  You need to use this instead:

```pascal
Onderdelen := Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount;
Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount := Onderdelen + 1;
Form3.StringGrid1.Cells[0, Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount - 1] := 'Hoofdstad';
```

Alternatively, since `Onderdelen` already contains the proper index value:

```pascal
Onderdelen := Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount;
Form3.StringGrid1.RowCount := Onderdelen + 1;
Form3.StringGrid1.Cells[0, Onderdelen] := 'Hoofdstad';
```